# Make a ASP.NET MVC method do work in a background queue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Primary issue: There's a block of code that I want to execute in the background. Please read further to understand what I mean by "background".

I am trying to perform external data posting through a an asynchronous/non-blocking thread. The main idea is that the user who submits the form need not wait for the external requests to complete.

The current flow is like this:

- User submits a form, with data
- Action processes the data performs internal steps like database updates, email notifications etc, and also uses **external resources** to post data using API
- User is taken to the "thank you page"

I am trying to decouple the `UploadFilesToAmazonAWSAndDropBoxAndFlickrAndGoogleDrive` from the regular user flow, as in the current setup, the user is waiting for the external API to complete. How to make `UploadFilesToAmazonAWSAndDropBoxAndFlickrAndGoogleDrive` run in a background thread?

Edit: Posting a rough outline of the code that I am trying to fix

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
    {
        //database operations, 
        InsertIntoDatabase(fc); //takes 1 second

        //3rd party posting
        //Takes about 30 seconds. 
       //Why it takes 30 seconds is obvious. Please let me know if this isn't obvious. 
        UploadFilesToAmazonAWSAndDropBoxAndFlickrAndGoogleDrive(fc); 

        //email operations
        SendEmails(fc); //takes 1 second

        //User is taken to Thank you page after 32 seconds. I want to reduce the time to 2 seconds
        return View("ThankYou"); 
    }
```

Comment: The short answer is this question is too broad. The medium answer is to move all of the logic into à `Task.Run`. The longer answer is to do something like @MitchellSellers says below (or preferably post to a queue and have an app outside of the web app processing the queue), and also to consider what and how to manage exceptions (e.g. database is down, SQS is down), failed emails, retries, compensating transactions etc etc. It is a very broad topic.

Comment: @mjwills, Managing exceptions, replaying failed requests, and all the plethora of things that can go wrong is outside the scope of what i asked.  I asked for a simple way to execute a block of code outside the regular program flow - with the end goal to improve application responsiveness. I thought this was a pretty common scenario for web developers to handle.

Comment: Making your Index method async would allow your thread to handle other requests while waiting for I/O. But the end user on their browser would still be waiting for you to finish. Unless you move work to a background job queue.

Comment: IMHO insert into the database, then query the database to drive your job queue. Mainly so you can retry your upload / email.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, I know I can make the Index method async, but that doesn't solve my issue at all. 
How to move to the work to a background job queue? that's what I was asking for in the question.

Comment: How you decide to handle failures and retries, how much traffic your site gets, how many servers / VMs you have, how you are handling S3 credentials.... Anything could change the answer, the question is too broad.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman,  I could write an while loop that would keep trying for 24Hrs. Or I could chose to ignore all failures. Why is it so hard to give a simple answer!

Comment: `I asked for a simple way to execute a block of code outside the regular program flow` Maybe re-read my `medium answer`again. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edited scenario and target, the following high-level options might work to get you there.

- You could use Task.Run to start a background thread for your `PostDataToExternalResources` method, but you will still need to manage any exceptions etc on your side.  Additionally, I wouldn't pass the form collection off to that method if you do it this way, just keep in mind that you wouldn't have guaranteed results
- You could use something like [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to turn that process into a background job, which has its own durability etc.  I again wouldn't pass the FormCollection in, but it could have better durability.

Since it seems that viewing the "Thank you" page is not dependent upon the tasks completing, I'd look at something durable/executable like HangFire for consistency and ease of management

Comment: Could you please edit the question to clarify what you are answering here? I.e. whether you are talking about client (WinForms/WPF/UWP) or server (ASP.Net MVC / WebAPI) scenarios?

Comment: I was speaking about ASP.NET